# What Source Control Integration Tool Works for PowerBuilder 12.5 and StarTeam 14

Tags: powerbuilder, starteam

We are upgrading from StarTeam 2009 to StarTeam 14 and I cannot find the replacement for the old StarTeam Microsoft SCC Integration.  Is there something out there that will work for this combination.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...  Microsoft SCC integration is still referenced in the StarTeam 14.2 installation guide.

http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/StarTeam/142/en/ST_Install_en.pdf

Maybe it was an installation option that you inadvertently left unchecked?